# How to find component inside P:Datalist in primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have component hierarchy such as this

```
    Form>P:DataList
    >DataTable1
    >DataTable2
```

When I see the generated html code or developers tool in ie, I found
the client id generated for the datatables are

```
    form:datalist:0:DataTable
    form:datalist:1:DataTable
```

However when I invoke 
        ViewRoot.findComponent
 with the above client Id,
it return null.When I removed the "rowIndex" value i.e 0/1
it then only returns the first datatable.
How to make it work so that I can find both the data tables
from backend using their Ids?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043218/refer-to-jsf-dynamically-generated-ids-based-on-iteration-index.

Comment: I tried something similar.Instead of c:foreach I tried with p:dataList.But when I was trying to add dynamic ids to the data tables, the "#{rowIndexvar}" was evaluating to null.So what am I missing here?

Comment: That server side, there is only one component instance that renders all of indexed ids.