# How to reuse code in ui:include with specific ids?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

If I want to reuse code like

```
<p:inputText id="[id]"/>
<p:commandButton update="[id]"/>
```

with '`ui:include`, e.g.

```
<ui:include src="[same source]"/>
<ui:include src="[same source]"/>
```

I need a unique id on the `p:inputText` which I could specify manually as `f:param` to `ui:include`. Is there a way to automate this - I imagine access to a unique value of an include context or something similar?

I read about [declaring ids in `ui:repeat` and other similar structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043218/refer-to-jsf-dynamically-generated-ids-based-on-iteration-index)/based on an iteration index, but in those cases it's clear in which context the reusage takes place.

Comment: Feel free to modify the example to refer to pure JSF (without Primefaces) - I'm not sure about the equivalent of the update attribute.

Comment: lt requires an `f:ajax` child tag

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269